# Как скрыть отклик api

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование

Можно ли скрыть вывод метода `res.json(что-то из json)`? Имеется в виду, если я перехожу на localhost, а котором реализуется api, там видны выводящиеся json объекты. Мне же нужно сделать так, чтобы их не было видно, но при этом получать информацию из вывода я мог.

Comment: Найтите реализацию и переопределить метод.

Comment: @AzizUmarov , а можно по-подробнее?

Comment: Это js если что-то выходить то кто то его печатает. Найти по исходнику это место и переделать ф-ю. Присвоить переделанную res.json = function ...

Comment: Js всегда открытый хоть и минимизирован. Исходники есть всегда

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Лучше переопределить или же самому переписать функцию вручную под свои нужды?

Comment: Сначала пишите потом переопределяете